# Force a file download from within a promise from $http.post

Tags: angularjs, download

I have the contents of a file from a REST call made to another service, and I need to force these contents into a mechanism to trigger a browser download mechanism. This is essentially driven by a hyperlink fired elsewhere that throws the reference ID to said file. The contents are returned in a Blob-parsable format.

The below code doesn't fire any event once the aforementioned link is clicked. Upon closer examination, it appears the hyperlink inserted never gets fired inside the scope of the promise. Is there a way to make this work as intended, or how should we refactor the link for this file download?

```
downloadDocument = function (id, fileName) {
    console.log("downloadDocument");
    documentsService.documentsFactory.retrieveDocument(id).then(
            function successCallback(response) {
                var a = document.createElement("a");
                a.style = "display: none";
                var file = new Blob([response], {type: 'application/pdf'});
                var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
                a.href = url;
                a.download = fileName;

                document.body.appendChild(a);
                a.click();
            },
            function errorCallback(response) {
                console.debug("Error with RetrieveDownload call", response);
            }
    );
};
```

Comment: does the link work as expected if you don't `display:none` it and click on it?

Comment: I removed the display none and while the link is present in the DOM, it will not respond to `click()` events or any other kind of events for that matter. In testing from the console, the element returns undefined. The content of the generated link is `<a href="blob:http%3A//testapp.local.com/66bbce35-3df1-4209-bcef-a45902d4c2b9" download="ExampleDoc.pdf"></a>`

Comment: is the `response` data correct?  what happens if you access directly the URL that `documentsService.documentsFactory.retrieveDocument(id)` hits?